# symfony authentication redirect fails

Tags: php, symfony

i wanna redirect users from login controller to homePage if has allready logged in :

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('mouvement_index');
    }

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    return $this->render('OCUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
        'error'         => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
    ));
}
```

but

```
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')
```

return null or false and render login page :/

Comment: Does it work with `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` ?

Comment: No it doesn't work with IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY , i use symfony 3+

Comment: Can you dump the current user please? **dump($this->getUser());** Or know the role associated with current user.

Comment: dump( app ) in login view :   "app" => AppVariable {#517 ▼
    -tokenStorage: TokenStorage {#262 ▼
      -token: AnonymousToken {#1620 ▼
        -secret: "58b01a56c763f2.28117583"
        -user: "anon."
        -roles: []
        -authenticated: true
        -attributes: []
      }
    }....

Comment: {{dump(app.user)}}  in mouvement view : User {#396 ▼
  -id: 14
  -username: "Admin"
  -password: "6XOvimcAIte5ryOzOd7lu4bWSvhdVRH97w=="
  -salt: ""
  -roles: array:1 [▼
    0 => "ROLE_ADMIN"
  ]
}